# facebook launch

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I wanted to launch facebook through a button from my application for which i was using the below code:

```
  private async void btn_facebook_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var op = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("Facebook:Social"));
    }
```

but it seems that facebook app didn't launch. Can anyone guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:"));
```

Should do the trick with installed app(http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e)

You can find more in http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List

Remember, launching custom uri scheme only works on Windows Phone 8 not 7.